# How to check for existing tablerow and if it already exists, to change it instead of creating a new one?

Tags: javascript, api, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to create an app that uses an API that gives new information every second. This information is taken through a websocket (socket.io). When the data of the total object is transferred to the client side, it should create a tablerow with some of the data corresponding to the name of the object.

**This is a part of the object received from the API**

```
{ eventType: '24hrTicker',
  eventTime: 1552416167544,
  symbol: 'ZRXBNB',
  priceChange: '0.00063000',
  percentChange: '3.571',
  averagePrice: '0.01780410',
  prevClose: '0.01776000',
  close: '0.01827000',
  closeQty: '200.00000000',
  bestBid: '0.01815000',
  bestBidQty: '1028.90000000',
  bestAsk: '0.01828000',
  bestAskQty: '589.00000000',
  open: '0.01764000',
  high: '0.01858000',
  low: '0.01726000',
  volume: '197350.10000000',
  quoteVolume: '3513.64020500',
  openTime: 1552329767540,
  closeTime: 1552416167540,
  firstTradeId: 4948,
  lastTradeId: 5281,
  numTrades: 334 }
{ eventType: '24hrTicker',
  eventTime: 1552416168270,
  symbol: 'ZRXUSDT',
  priceChange: '0.01380000',
  percentChange: '5.347',
  averagePrice: '0.26415650',
  prevClose: '0.25780000',
  close: '0.27190000',
  closeQty: '648.50000000',
  bestBid: '0.27190000',
  bestBidQty: '3607.03000000',
  bestAsk: '0.27300000',
  bestAskQty: '1196.01000000',
  open: '0.25810000',
  high: '0.27850000',
  low: '0.24930000',
  volume: '2710750.57000000',
  quoteVolume: '716062.38319800',
  openTime: 1552329768267,
  closeTime: 1552416168267,
  firstTradeId: 40021,
  lastTradeId: 44116,
  numTrades: 4096 }
{ eventType: '24hrTicker',
  eventTime: 1552416168170,
  symbol: 'FETBNB',
  priceChange: '-0.00053000',
  percentChange: '-3.411',
  averagePrice: '0.01512124',
  prevClose: '0.01554000',
  close: '0.01501000',
  closeQty: '84.60000000',
  bestBid: '0.01498000',
  bestBidQty: '3603.60000000',
  bestAsk: '0.01508000',
  bestAskQty: '1416.70000000',
  open: '0.01554000',
  high: '0.01665000',
  low: '0.01414000',
  volume: '15016967.00000000',
  quoteVolume: '227075.23396700',
  openTime: 1552329768166,
  closeTime: 1552416168166,
  firstTradeId: 149059,
  lastTradeId: 154620,
  numTrades: 5562 }
{ eventType: '24hrTicker',
  eventTime: 1552416168453,
  symbol: 'FETBTC',
  priceChange: '-0.00000060',
  percentChange: '-1.024',
  averagePrice: '0.00005741',
  prevClose: '0.00005857',
  close: '0.00005800',
  closeQty: '26057.00000000',
  bestBid: '0.00005780',
  bestBidQty: '126.00000000',
  bestAsk: '0.00005794',
  bestAskQty: '2033.00000000',
  open: '0.00005860',
  high: '0.00006217',
  low: '0.00005455',
  volume: '45952459.00000000',
  quoteVolume: '2638.19720144',
  openTime: 1552329768449,
  closeTime: 1552416168449,
  firstTradeId: 1070694,
  lastTradeId: 1108815,
  numTrades: 38122 }
{ eventType: '24hrTicker',
  eventTime: 1552416168472,
  symbol: 'FETUSDT',
  priceChange: '-0.00140000',
  percentChange: '-0.618',
  averagePrice: '0.22380295',
  prevClose: '0.22640000',
  close: '0.22500000',
  closeQty: '2776.62000000',
  bestBid: '0.22470000',
  bestBidQty: '222.52000000',
  bestAsk: '0.22490000',
  bestAskQty: '1416.72000000',
  open: '0.22640000',
  high: '0.24140000',
  low: '0.20870000',
  volume: '37116510.87000000',
  quoteVolume: '8306784.57211700',
  openTime: 1552329768464,
  closeTime: 1552416168464,
  firstTradeId: 678606,
  lastTradeId: 703455,
  numTrades: 24}
```

This is the ejs code I use to check for an existing row, so that it doesn't create a new one but just updates the existing tablerow with the id of the symbol that contains the symboldata.

**EJS CODE**

```
<script>
                    var tabelBody = document.getElementById("coinDataTabel");
                    var testData = document.getElementById("test");
                    var symbol = [];
                    var existingRow;
                    var currentPair;

                    socket.on("coins", function(allCoinData){
                        if(allCoinData["symbol"].substr(allCoinData["symbol"].length - 3) == "BTC"){
                            currentPair = symbol.find(function(){
                                return allCoinData["symbol"];
                            });
                            if(currentPair == true){
                                testData.innerHTML = "<p>"+"symbol find is true!"+"</p>";
                                existingRow = document.getElementById(allCoinData["symbol"]);
                                existingRow.innerHTML = "<td>"+allCoinData["symbol"]+"</td>"+"<td>"+allCoinData["high"]+"</td>"+"<td>"+allCoinData["low"]+"</td>"+"<td>"+allCoinData["close"]+"</td>";
                            } else {
                                testData.innerHTML = "<p>"+"symbol find is false!"+"</p>";
                                symbol.push(allCoinData["symbol"]);
                                tabelBody.innerHTML += "<tr id="+allCoinData["symbol"]+">"+"<td>"+allCoinData["symbol"]+"</td>"+"<td>"+allCoinData["high"]+"</td>"+"<td>"+allCoinData["low"]+"</td>"+"<td>"+allCoinData["close"]+"</td>"+"</tr>";   
                            }
                        }
                    });
                </script>
```

The code checks for any symbol that ends with 'BTC'. All the other symbols are skipped in this example. After that, I tried to do a check if the array symbol already contains the same symbol as the API returns on that point. if so, it should update the row that already exsists, instead of creating a new one.

Please help me out because I have tried so many different things, but none worked properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what I understand, you have rows in your table with id being the symbol from your data.

So instead of maintaining an array of symbols separately, you can check for the existence of row(tr) with an id of the incoming symbol using **document.getElementById(allCoinData["symbol"])**.

If the row exists, update the row(tr) else create a new one.

Something like this.

```js
socket.on("coins", function(allCoinData){
  existingRow = document.getElementById(allCoinData["symbol"]);
  if(!!existingRow){
    testData.innerHTML = "<p>"+"symbol find is true!"+"</p>";
    existingRow = document.getElementById(allCoinData["symbol"]);
    existingRow.innerHTML = "<td>"+allCoinData["symbol"]+"</td>"+"<td>"+allCoinData["high"]+"</td>"+"<td>"+allCoinData["low"]+"</td>"+"<td>"+allCoinData["close"]+"</td>";
  } else {
      testData.innerHTML = "<p>"+"symbol find is false!"+"</p>";
      symbol.push(allCoinData["symbol"]);
      tabelBody.innerHTML += "<tr id="+allCoinData["symbol"]+">"+"<td>"+allCoinData["symbol"]+"</td>"+"<td>"+allCoinData["high"]+"</td>"+"<td>"+allCoinData["low"]+"</td>"+"<td>"+allCoinData["close"]+"</td>"+"</tr>";   
  }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works fine. Is it also possible to sort the tablerows (first column with the symbols) to alphabetic order? Like ADA, BTC, ZEC for example?

Comment: @DannyHoekstra to sort the table rows in alphabetical order what you can do is,

maintain an array of symbols which are sorted. Add symbol into it in alphabetical order using any sort algorithm. Whenever you push a symbol into it, insert a row in your table at the same index as in your array. 

Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow for inserting rows in the table. 
The insertRow function accepts index at which you want to insert the element.

So if you are inserting symbol in array at position 0, you insert row in the table using insertRow(0).